# For K-means clusters, how can I ensure each cluster has a minimum of n numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I usually use k-means++ for initialization, which is considered to be the most effective.
But sometimes, this results in some clusters having too few constituents.
While this may be mathematically more effective, for my purpose it does not serve well.

What kind of initialization method can I use to ensure that each cluster has at least n number of constituents?
Reducing the number of n_clusters may help but that is not preferable.
Or are there any alternative methods I can use to solve this problem?

I am using python sklearn.cluster for KMeans.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There **isn't** such an initialization strategy. One simple reason is that if you select a large-enough value for $k$, there will definitely be some centroids with few samples assigned to them.

One solution could be to **remove** centroids with a small number of samples assigned to them, after the algorithm has finished. This technique is similar to *pruning* in Decision Trees.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Faiss-building-blocks:-clustering,-PCA,-quantization). Its clustering model has options like: `min_points_per_centroid`/ `max_points_per_centroid`. It has kmeans, but I am not sure whether it has kmeans++.